# What should I write under "signed" tag?

Tags: formality, cultural-correctness

Signing english documents (UK, if that changes anything) I am wondering what should I write under "Signed" tag? I wouldn't have doubts if the blank would be described as "Signature", but "Signed"? And the following is "Date". So maybe I should give a city name there? In Poland we do so - City, DD.MM.YYYY
And signature follows...

So should I sign or give a city name there?

By the way if I am a man, under "maiden name" should I put a hyphen or leave it blank, or should I repeat my surname?

Comment: Signed generally indicates signature requested in the corresponding entry point. Don't over think this. Date format in the UK: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68844/date-format-in-uk-vs-us . Europe goes from small (day) to large (year). US uses MM/DD/YYYY which does make for some interesting conversations regarding January 12 versus December 1.

Comment: I think the only reason for specifying *where* you signed some document (country, city, address, etc.) would be in contexts where this might influence a later decision about *which nation's legal system* should govern the interpretation of the document. But it seems like a rather antiquated practice/concept to me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about what is meant by field labels in a particular official form. For instance, there is no way to know, just by knowing English, **what the officials expect** for a *maiden name* field, if the signer is male. You need to follow official instructions for official forms. Contact the officials if you have a question about what is meant.

Answer (score 1):

Signed: Use your signature

Date: dd/mm/yy

Maiden Name: Leave blank unless you are using a married name in which case state your original family name