# Is there any word in English for the date after interchanged day and month digit?

Tags: single-word-requests, dates

For example, my friend's anniversary is on 3rd August (03/08/2016-dd/mm/yyyy). If I interchange the Month and Day digit and write 08/03/2016 meaning 8th March, is there any special word for this kind of date in English? Like 'Reverse Date' or something. Ignoring the dates after 12th.

Editing: I am not confused about date formats here. Think it like, If I want to wish my friend on 8th of March (instead of 3rd August), what should I say him? Like: *'Happy Reversed Anniversary'*!?

Comment: Related: [Date format in UK vs US](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68844/date-format-in-uk-vs-us).

Comment: Do you mean mm/did/yyyy in the second instance? That would be the US date format. If not, you might say they used the wrong date format.

Comment: Confused dates!

Comment: @Lawrence, no, I wrote it intentionally.

Comment: Even if such a word existed, it must be vanishingly rare, it would defeat your purpose. If someone's birthday is on March 8th send them a card on that date, and there's nothing to stop you from sending the same person a second card on August 3rd and coining your own word.

Comment: Could you say 'Happy American Anniversary"  - as many people know that Americans use the reverse form so he may get it. I think it's a great excuse for a celebration.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, well Cards and anniversary are just for explanation. I'm looking for the particular word, which shows the relationship of 8th March with 3rd August and 1st December with 12th January :)

Comment: @Ankur If it was intentional, they either got the date or the format wrong. No *single-word term* for swapping the day and month of a date comes to mind.

Comment: I'm not aware of any generally-accepted term in the US, other than "wrong" or "confused".  I generally use the format "8 Mar 2017" to avoid any possible confusion.

Comment: Sure you mean if you want to wish them this on March (the) Third, not the Third of March. :)  Month-first is a speech thing, and the numeric digits merely a reflection of the same.

Comment: @tchrist There goes the *Fourth of July*. :)

Comment: @Lawrence It is our joy and our delight to extend to both you and your lady wife the honor of an invitation to attend the graduation ceremony of our belovèd son Vernon Ebenezer Milton-FitzReine on Sunday the Twenty-First Day of May in the Year of our Lord One Thousand Eight Hundred and Thirty-Seven at Three Hours of the Afternoon, with formal luncheon to follow in the pavilion.

Comment: @tchrist Thank you kindly. I hope the graduation went well, but I'll have to offer my apologies as unfortunately the invitation was held up in the post. My compliments on the excellent formatting of your dates.

Comment: @davidlol I have a November 9th birthday. If I received this card on September 11th I'd do a bit of a double take

Comment: Perhaps it would be more common to consider this if more than about 12 birthdays in 30\* (40%) still led to a meaningful date in the wrong system. \* Of course there are 30.4 days in the average month (30.5 if you consider just leap years)

Comment: As a fan of portmanteaus, I think you should wish them a Happy Anni-Reversary.

Comment: I recommend switching the expression of the dates in the question from dd/mm/yyyy format to yyyy-mm-dd [ISO date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), to make it clearer that US format has nothing to do with the question, and that the result of this process is not intrinsically in US or any other format.

Comment: Is there a word for this in some other language? Why would you imagine there is a word for this in English?

Comment: @cloudfeet I wish you had posted that as an answer...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

While it's difficult to prove a negative, having grown up speaking English and being fairly well-read, I feel safe saying:

> **No**, there is no commonly used word for this that would immediately be understood by the majority of people.

Comment: @Josh OP isn't asking about the name of the format

Comment: @Josh, see his edit. He's asking if there is a term in English for when a date represented as mm/dd/yy is also a valid date if interpreted as dd/mm/yy.

Comment: @Josh He's not asking about the name of the date format, he's asking about the name of a joke/intentional misuse of date formats

Comment: @Josh: US date format does not appear in the question. All dates are explicitly in dd/mm/yyyy format. Date formats are not relevant.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai: No it's not: "If I interchange the Month and Day digit and write 08/03/2016 **(dd/mm/yyyy)**".

Comment: @user2357112 you're right oops

Answer (score 13):

***[Middle-endian](https://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2013/dec/16/why-do-americans-write-the-month-before-the-day)*** *date format* appears to be the technical term, more commonly known as the ***[US date format](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/calendar/writingthedate/)***, see also [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=US%20date%20format&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CU.S.%20date%20format%3B%2Cc0):

> - Despite the variety of date formats used around world, the US is the only country to use the mm/dd/yy format.
> - This condition is diagnosed as middle-endianness. Seriously. It comes from computer science where bytes are arranged according to their size. If the order has larger ones at the front, it's known as big-endian and so too are dates formatted with the years first (see the likes of China and Mongolia in the map).

[image]

(www.theguardian.com)

Comment: Don't the Chinese still use vertical script in certain areas?

Comment: This is quite useful @Josh, but date format is not my confusion :)

Comment: @Ankur Well, you could say "Happy Middle-Endian Birthday".

Comment: @Ankur - the "reverse" format (mm/dd/yy) is called what I said in my answer. What definition you want to use for your friend is really up to you.

Comment: Fascinating map!

Comment: According to that map Canadians wouldn't know whether they're coming or going, and I wonder what the cutoff for including `yyyy-mm-dd` is (many blue countries must be close to being green)

Comment: The map also appears to have Palau and FS Micronesia in red, despite the article's claim that only the US is.

Comment: Oh Kenya. Of all the pairs to choose, you chose the worst two.

Comment: Both dates in the question are expressed in dd/mm/yyyy format. US date format is not used at all.

Comment: @Josh: No format change is involved, only a change of the actual date. You could do the same thing regardless of whether the date was originally expressed in little-endian, big-endian, or US date format. Calling this process "US date format" would be especially confusing if you were already expressing dates in US format, in particular.

Comment: @Josh: The question is asking whether there's a word for the new date obtained by switching the day and month numbers of an old date (not the new representation of a date obtained by switching the positions of the day and month numbers in the old representation of a date).

Comment: This is a good answer to a different question, and would be upvoted if that were the question.

Comment: @ChrisH As a Canadian, I can say it's a serious annoyance.  I'm a stalwart `dd/mm/yyyy` guy but it drives me nuts that this country can't make up its mind about date formats.  Even worse, it's not entirely uncommon to also still see `yy-mm-dd` in some places - you end up having to find other related items or documents to cross reference by elimination which ones could be the days, months, or years.

Answer (score 10):

A possibility would be to call it a "transposed" birthday.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but as it stands this isn't a good answer. It would be much improved by a definition of "transposed" and a reference/link for where you got that definition from.

Comment: Transposed date is the typical term I use and hear when dealing with data entry systems and the people that use them. It's a bit ambiguous though, because besides month/day transpositions, there are also day transpositions (1/21/2017 vs. 1/12/2017). Without more specific language though, if I just heard "transposed date" I would be assumed to be month/day.

Comment: Accepted @Kevin's answer as 'transposed' can create ambiguity, but +1 for now, I'm wishing him 'Happy transposed Anniversary' :)

Comment: @Ankur Although your question has nothing to do with date formats, seeing as month and day *do* get transposed on crossing the Big Pond between the UK and US, and seeing as there is no *real* word for what you want, how about calling it a "[transponded](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transpondian)" birthday?

Answer (score 6):

As a tongue-in-cheek in joke, I'd call this a:

**UK Birthday** - if you're normally using mm/dd/yyyy and transposing it to dd/mm/yyyy.

**U.S. Birthday** - if you're normally using dd/mm/yyyy and transposing it to mm/dd/yyyy.

These aren't widely used or 'correct' by any reasonable way, but in a joking sense I think a friend or colleague would get what you're doing in context. "It's your U.S. Birthday today!"

Comment: Or even "Happy American Anniversary" ;-)

Answer (score 4):

As has been mentioned in other answers, there's no universally understood word that I can think of (native US English speaker).

However, colloquially and in business, I've seen the `dd/mm/yyyy` format referred to as the **"European Format"/"European Date Format"**.

So, you could perhaps congratulate and say "Happy European Anniversary!"

(Here's at least one use of ["European Format"](https://britishisms.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/european-date-format/) in practice.)

(Also, it's a little more special for those folks who got married/started dating/whatever in the first 12 days of the month. If you were married July 13, you don't get a "European Anniversary" in the US format since 13/07/20xx never comes up. )

Comment: OP is the other way around - dd/mm/yyyy standard, and looking for an alternative name - the mm/dd/yyyy format is *almost* exclusive to the USA - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Comment: @Rycochet - D'oh, then yeah I'd go with "USA Birthday" or "USA Format".