# When writing out month and year in words, is any punctuation necessary?

Tags: american-english, punctuation

Trying to write out "August" and "two thousand eighteen" but unsure how to concatenate these two -- just a space, or is a comma needed?

A) August two thousand eighteen
----OR----
B) August, two thousand eighteen

The post found on Grammarly's blog [here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/how-to-write-dates/) seems to suggest the former, but it also has the day in there, so I wasn't sure. Couldn't find any other info regarding this online, and all similar questions on here have numbers in the year instead of words.
Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: just to specify -- American English, not in a sentence at all (literally just the words "august two thousand eighteen", context is an informal publication, so I suppose (in hindsight) this is all more a stylistic choice than anything else.

Comment: What’s the entire sentence in which this is intended to occur? Is it anything like [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/377376/is-there-any-word-in-english-for-the-date-after-interchanged-day-and-month-digit#comment885514_377376) by chance? :)

Comment: It is a bit strange that you wouldn't include the day. The fully spelled-out format suggests a highly formal context (like an invitation to a wedding/graduation/etc., or the date on a diploma), but such contexts normally require the full date. On diplomas, for instance, you'd say something like *Given at Berkeley this twelfth day of June in the year two thousand and two.*

Comment: Please specify the brand of English you're asking about with tags [american-english] or [british-english] (or something else, of course). Dates are markedly different on each coast of the Atlantic.

Comment: @tchrist no sentence, it was only the "august 2018" I wanted on there -- was using it for a publication of sorts (which, in hind sight, I suppose makes it all a stylistic choice anyways)

Comment: @linguisticturn didn't want to put a day because it was a few days and I didn't like the way the publication looked with numbers in the text; context of the publication didn't necessitate 100% proper English, I was just curious which was correct

Comment: @AndrewLeach American English :)

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t speak really American English but I would just write “August 2018”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Years should be written numerically (recommended by Chicago and APA guides). Assuming this is a special circumstance (wedding announcement is Google's top hit), you would use option A. Commas are only required in dates when numbers or weekdays are involved (e.g., "Sunday, January 4, 2018"). Additionally, if this is a formal announcement, the year is often given it's own line anyway, but that's a stylistic opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There is precedent for

*In the month of August in the year two thousand eighteen.*

Some attested examples (all from the 1800s):

> **In the month of January in the year eighteen hundred and ninety-seven** the mayor shall appoint one person to be a member of the board of health...
>   ([*An Act to Revise the Charter of the City of Holyoke*](https://books.google.com/books?id=wERGAQAAMAAJ&q=%22in+the+month+of+January+in+the+year%22&dq=%22in+the+month+of+January+in+the+year%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjqLz43f3dAhVCRqwKHTmZD9sQ6AEINDAC))
>   Personally appeared before me, B. B. Breedin, a justice of the peace in and for Mobile county Curtis Lewis, for a long time one of the custom-house officers for the district of Mobile, to me well known, who, being duly sworn on the Holy Evangelists of Almighty God, did solemnly swear that he went into the service of Benjamin S. Smoot and Dennison Darling, who were sutlers in copartnership for the second regiment of United States' infantry, **in the month of February, in the year eighteen hundred and thirteen.** [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ARNFAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22being%20duly%20sworn%20on%20the%20Holy%20Evangelists%20of%20Almighty%20God%2C%20did%20solemnly%20swear%20that%20he%20went%20into%20the%20service%20of%20Benjamin%20S.%20Smoot%20and%20Dennison%20Darling%2C%20who%20were%20sutlers%20in%20copartnership%20for%20the%20second%20regiment%20of%20United%20States'%20infantry%2C%20in%20the%20month%20of%20February%2C%20in%20the%20year%20eighteen%20hundred%20and%20thirteen%22&pg=PA682#v=onepage&q=%22being%20duly%20sworn%20on%20the%20Holy%20Evangelists%20of%20Almighty%20God,%20did%20solemnly%20swear%20that%20he%20went%20into%20the%20service%20of%20Benjamin%20S.%20Smoot%20and%20Dennison%20Darling,%20who%20were%20sutlers%20in%20copartnership%20for%20the%20second%20regiment%20of%20United%20States'%20infantry,%20in%20the%20month%20of%20February,%20in%20the%20year%20eighteen%20hundred%20and%20thirteen%22&f=false)
>   ...deposeth and saith, that **in the month of June, in the Year One Thousand Eight Hundred and Eleven,** he was engaged to the Hudson's Bay Company for three years. [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=GqUNAAAAQAAJ&dq=%22in%20the%20month%20of%20June%20in%20the%20year%22&pg=RA1-PA25#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20month%20of%20June%20in%20the%20year%22&f=false)
>   ...or if it be found necessary, such One or more consecutive Days, **in the Month of *July* in the Year One thousand eight hundred and forty-one,** as the said Lord Lieutenant or other Chief Governor or Governors ahall fix, severally visit every House within such Districts as may be assigned to them respectively... [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=LMIuAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22in%20the%20month%20of%20July%20in%20the%20year%22&pg=PA443#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20month%20of%20July%20in%20the%20year%22&f=false)

In many examples, instead of just the word *year*, we have  *year of our Lord*, as in

> ...in and for the county of Jefferson, **in the month of August, in the year of our Lord, one thousand eight hundred and seven,** whereat the said George Tod sat as judge in a certain cause... [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=1T0rAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22in%20the%20month%20of%20August%20in%20the%20year%22&pg=RA1-PA53#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20month%20of%20August%20in%20the%20year%22&f=false)

Sometimes it's *year of grace*

> Forget that I ever bored you with my rights and my wrongs, and I'll tell you exactly what befel me not six months ago; that is to say, **in the month of August in the year of grace one thousand eight hundred and fifty-two**.  [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=HEQFAAAAQAAJ&dq=%22in%20the%20month%20of%20August%20in%20the%20year%20of%20Grace%22&pg=PA30#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20month%20of%20August%20in%20the%20year%20of%20Grace%22&f=false)

Finally, and less commonly, we sometimes have ***of*** the year:

> After the town of Pontorson was taken again by the earl of Warwick in the manner related above, **in the month of May of the year one thousand four hundred and twenty-nine**... [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=wHo0GieV_8EC&lpg=PA154&dq=%22in%20the%20month%20of%20May%20of%20the%20year%22&pg=PA154#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20month%20of%20May%20of%20the%20year%22&f=false)

Comment: You see this in conveyances and leases - even modern ones ...not to endorse legalisms as any kind of guide to good English practice.

Answer (score 0):

One would assume that originally, once Pope Gregory XIII had instituted the new calendar, dates were written in the following manner:

> **On the** [First ... Second ... Third ...etc] **Day of August of** [the Year
>   of Our Lord]  **Two Thousand and Eighteen** ... [your text here,
>   describing the event you have in mind].

Anything else is an abbreviation of some sort of the above.

Because English orthography was in many ways similar to German at that juncture, all nouns and pronouns would be capitalized, whilst prepositions, conjunctions, and articles would not: a tradition that persists in newspaper headlines to this day.

That said, both the day of the month and the year are presented as numbers now; spelling them out would be viewed as archaic.