# Pronunciation of “Jan. 3”

Tags: pronunciation, dates

Is a date written “Jan. 3” pronounced *January **third***, or is it pronounced *January **three***?

Comment: True. Or, "the third of January," or (more informally) "three Jan." More about that at [this related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70122/how-do-i-formally-speak-dates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Jan. 3” is pronounced *January third*, which is why some people write it *January 3<sup>**rd**</sup>*.  You never pronounce that as *three* used that way.

Comment: I don't want get in a huge debate, but I think there is often scant correlation between how a date is written, and how it is pronounced. I might write a date in the style `3 Jan 13` but say it as "January third twenty-thirteen." Or, I might read a date transcribed as `Jan 3, 2013`, but say "The third of January of this year." How dates are written, spoken, and pronounced depends largely on situational context, preferred style, and cultural nuances.

Comment: @J.R. What's the debate about? I believe tchrist is saying that when used in a date, you pronounce it "third", never "three".

Comment: @Charles: I say "three" sometimes, as in, "My appointment is on three Jan." (That might be due in part to past service in the military; the military uses – and sometimes says – the numeral, not the ordinal). As for "debate", the last time I brought this issue up, it stirred quite a controversy (see the link in my comment to the O.P. above).

Comment: I'd have been okay with "seldom" or "unusually", but not "never".