# Is it common to omit the preposition "of" when referring to dates in British English

Tags: american-english, british-english, dates, formatting

In American English, we usually refer to dates using the month-day format. So the date today is spoken as "August eleven" without requiring the preposition "of". However, as far as I know, days are indicated first in British English. Thus, the same date is spoken as "Eleventh of August" requiring the preposition "of".

My question is, is it common to omit the "of" when speaking? Does "Eleventh of August" become "Eleventh August" sometimes? In addition to that, is saying the cardinal form (Eleven August) also used sometimes instead of the ordinal form (Eleven**th** August)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I formally speak dates?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70122/how-do-i-formally-speak-dates)

Comment: Does [this answer your question](https://youtu.be/oiF-QoNRNzs?t=139)? Notice they write "11th September" in print and pronounce it with the "of" when speaking.

Answer (score -4):

I can answer this by proposing a hypothesis; if you're looking for the 'most common usage,  right now'.

Hypothesis: It is possible to pinpoint almost any popular grammer usage with an internet search engine's 'search operator' feature. [ https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en ]

Strengths: As long as the internet search engine's  search operators and other filtering abilities work near flawlessly, we can search 'the usage' in any language in any country.

Weaknesses: As Google Search suggested [i couldn't spent necessary time to find the source but feel free to look in their product forums: https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=search+operator+result+site%3Aproductforums.google.com ] some operators can't work as intended especially when used together. In that case it was suggested that not using that operator.

Solution [to the Problem]: Use an internet search engine and input the words you şant to search in these characters; if their search operator supports that: "" [This will search the words exactly the way you have wrote and exclude the all other combinations.] Then use the country filter or search operator to show results from a specific country. This way you can compare total results numbers with each other. The higher one has the most common usage.